# Log files defined in logging profiles cannot be accessed by management interface in WildFly

Tags: wildfly

I have a WildFly 15.0.1 running in domain mode in a Docker container. It has two logging profiles configured - one for each application deployed on it. When I log in to the HAL Management Console via browser I can see all the logs and their file sizes, but I can only view and download the `server.log` one.

Trying to download one of the others results in:

```
"WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[
    (\"subsystem\" => \"logging\"),
    (\"log-file\" => \"custom-log-file.log\")
]' not found"
```

which makes sense as in JBoss CLI those log files are not available directly under logging subsystem, but rather in logging profile details. Is there any way to make them available in the HAL Management Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is a [bug](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/HAL-1628) that was solved in *HAL 3.0.17.Final*. Since *WildFly 15.0.1.Final* contains *HAL 3.0.6.Final* and *WildFly 16.0.0.Final* contains *HAL 3.1.2.Final*, upgrading to WildFly 16 is one possible solution. The other is to upgrade just the HAL module in WildFly as described [here](https://github.com/hal/console#replace-existing-console).